# How to add buttons of add and delete with each dynamic row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I make a dynamic form but when i click add row it add row at the last and when i click remove button it remove the last row i want to add(2 buttons one for add and one for delete with each row when i click add row it adds row below the entire row and if i click delete row it delete the entire row not last row).i want to make design like this:
[image]

and here is my code of dynamic fields:

```
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
     <select class="items" name="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" id="items"><option value="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option></select>
     <textarea name="description" id="description" class="description" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:209px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;"></textarea>
     <input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice" class="unitprice" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px -1px 0;">
     <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="quantity" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:64px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;">
     <select name="firsttax" id="firsttax" style=" float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px -1px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected" ></option></select>
     <select name="secondtax" id="secondtax" style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected"></option></select>
     <input type="text" name="linetotal" id="linetotal" class="linetotal" placeholder="0.00" readonly style="float:right; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; background-color: #F0F0F0; text-align:right; margin: -31px -1px 0;">         
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="itemscounter" name="itemscounter" value=""/>
```

and here is javascript code to generate dynamic fields:

```
$('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
       $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
        var newNum = num + 1;

    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
        newElem.find(':input').each(function () {
            $('form select[name=items]').attr('name', 'items'+newNum);
            $('form select[id=items]').attr('id', 'items'+newNum);

    $('form textarea[name=description]').attr('name', 'description'+newNum);
    $('form textarea[id=description]').attr('id', 'description'+newNum);    
    $('form input[name=unitprice]').attr('name', 'unitprice'+newNum);
    $('form input[id=unitprice]').attr('id', 'unitprice'+newNum);

    $('form input[name=quantity]').attr('name', 'quantity'+newNum);
    $('form input[id=quantity]').attr('id', 'quantity'+newNum);

    $('form select[name=firsttax]').attr('name', 'firsttax'+newNum);
    $('form select[id=firsttax]').attr('id', 'firsttax'+newNum);

    $('form select[name=secondtax]').attr('name', 'secondtax'+newNum);
    $('form select[id=secondtax]').attr('id', 'secondtax'+newNum);

    $('form input[name=linetotal]').attr('name', 'linetotal'+newNum);
    $('form input[id=linetotal]').attr('id', 'linetotal'+newNum);
    $('#itemscounter').val(+newNum);
    });

    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function() {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

        $('#input' + num).remove();
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled',false);
        if (num-1 === 1)
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
   });

   $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

and here is buttons:

```
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAdd" value="Add Row" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDel" value="Remove Row" />
```

and here is my screenshots:

[image]

Which changing in my code to make above picture like delete line and add line with each row?

Comment: Add a fiddle with minimum code showing your problem completely.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J5Akd/

Comment: here is my code i want to attach add and remove buttons with each row same as above picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var cloned = $('#table').find('tr:eq(1)').clone()
        cloned.removeClass('.row');
        $('#table').append(cloned);
    });

        $('#btnDel').click(function() {
            $('#table').find('tr:last').remove();
        });

 });
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J5Akd/1/)**